# How to select users that exist in one group and only that group - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a list of users that only exist in a single group and no other groups. The users can be in multiple groups.

The group I want to get users in has an ID of 20064212 and belongs to the acc_id 200640

There are three tables involved:

**Users**

USER_PK_ID,
ACC_ID,
Active,
Deleted

**USER_GROUP_USER**
GROUP_ID, USER_PK_ID

**USER_GROUP**
ID,
ACC_ID,
DESCRIPTION,
ACTIVE

I can get all the users in the group with the fallowing query but it does not exclude users that exist in other groups also.

```
       SELECT DISTINCT (U.USER_PK_ID)
       FROM USER_GROUP_USER U
       JOIN USERS US ON US.USER_PK_ID = U.USER_PK_ID
       WHERE GROUP_ID = 20064212
       AND US.acc_id = 200640
       AND US.DELETED = 'N'
```

I have tried various queries but they always seem to return users that also exist in other groups

```
SELECT DISTINCT (U.USER_PK_ID)
FROM USER_GROUP_USER U
JOIN USERS US ON US.USER_PK_ID = U.USER_PK_ID
WHERE GROUP_ID = 20064212
AND US.acc_id = 200640
AND US.DELETED = 'N'
AND GROUP_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM USER_GROUP
    WHERE acc_id = 200640
    AND ID != 20064212)
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT U.USER_PK_ID`, to make code clearer.

Comment: Count distinct group id per user and select only those who has a count = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping I parsed your text correctly; this SQL returns users with ACC_ID= 200640 and DELETE='N' and that are member of group with ID 20064212, but not member of any other group.

```
select u.user_pk_id
from users u 
  join user_group_user ugu on (u.user_pk_id = ugu.user_pk_id) 
  join user_group ug on ugu.group_id=ug.id
where ugu.group_id=20064212 
and u.acc_id=200640
and u.deleted='N'
and not exists (
    select null
    from user_group_user ugu2
    where ugu2.group_id != ugu.group_id
    and ugu.user_pk_id = ugu2.user_pk_id
);
```